# Kendoui-rails installing in public

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4, and I am trying to install Kendoui-rails using:

```
    "rails kendoui:install"
```

the thing is that rails 4 uses rails-sprockets, so the jscript and stylesheet are at app/assets dir. but even using the sprockets it keeps installing it on the public folder.

when you run the command it suppose to look like this:

```
  // app/assets/javascripts/application.js
  //= require kendo/kendo.all.min

  /* app/assets/stylesheets/application.css */
  *= require kendo/kendo.common.min
  *= require kendo/kendo.default.min
```

instead, at least for me it shows this:

```
     copying  Kendo UI (2013.1.319) javascripts
  create  public/javascripts/jquery.min.js
  create  public/javascripts/kendo.web.min.js
 copying  Kendo UI (2013.1.319) stylesheets
  create  public/stylesheets/kendo.common.min.css
  create  public/stylesheets/textures
  create  public/stylesheets/textures/brushed-metal.png
  create  public/stylesheets/textures/dots1.png
  create  public/stylesheets/textures/dots10.png
  create  public/stylesheets/textures/dots11.png
  create  public/stylesheets/textures/dots12.png
  create  public/stylesheets/textures/dots13.png
  create  public/stylesheets/textures/dots2.png
  create  public/stylesheets/textures/dots3.png
  create  public/stylesheets/textures/dots4.png
  create  public/stylesheets/textures/dots5.png
  create  public/stylesheets/textures/dots6.png
  create  public/stylesheets/textures/dots7.png
  create  public/stylesheets/textures/dots8.png
  create  public/stylesheets/textures/dots9.png
  create  public/stylesheets/textures/glass-lighter.png
  create  public/stylesheets/textures/glass.png
  create  public/stylesheets/textures/highlight.png
  create  public/stylesheets/textures/hsv-gradient.png
  create  public/stylesheets/textures/hue.png
  create  public/stylesheets/textures/leather1.png
  create  public/stylesheets/textures/leather2.png
  create  public/stylesheets/textures/noise.png
  create  public/stylesheets/textures/stripe1.png
  create  public/stylesheets/textures/stripe2.png
  create  public/stylesheets/textures/stripe3.png
  create  public/stylesheets/textures/stripe4.png
  create  public/stylesheets/textures/stripe5.png
  create  public/stylesheets/textures/stripe6.png
  create  public/stylesheets/textures/transparency.png
  create  public/stylesheets/textures/transtexture.png
  create  public/stylesheets/kendo.default.min.css
```

Could not find "stylesheets/kendo/default" in any of your source paths. Your current source paths are: 
/home/charlie/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@potsuri/gems/kendoui-rails-0.1.1/vendor/assets

I really don't understand what i have to do to solve this problem. Any Idea?

Answer (score 2):

I could not get it to work with the asset pipeline in Rails 4 either. [The latest commit was a year ago](https://github.com/kendo-labs/kendo-rails/commit/eeae6fb0cc74b18466ddbdd1e88775f1d36f7133), just after Rails 4 came out. However, [the commit history](https://github.com/kendo-labs/kendo-rails/commits/master) does not reveal any intentions of implementing compatibility with Rails 4. [KendoUI-Rails seems to be a dead project](https://github.com/kendo-labs/kendo-rails/issues/8).

The problem seems to be specifically [this line](https://github.com/kendo-labs/kendo-rails/blob/master/lib/rails/generators/kendoui/install/install_generator.rb#L4), where Kendo is asking Rails whether the asset pipeline is enabled. This mechanism has apparently changed in Rails 4 and so the check returns `nil` in a fresh install of Rails 4:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.enabled
#=> nil
```

As a quick workaround, you could however copy the [code of the asset pipeline compatible generator](https://github.com/kendo-labs/kendo-rails/blob/master/lib/rails/generators/kendoui/install/install_generator.rb#L43-L85) (just the class), rename the class to `KendouiInstallGenerator` and put it in a file called `lib/generators/kendoui_install_generator.rb`. This will enable you to run the `kendoui_install` generator (note the underscore).

```
$ rails generate kendoui_install
      adding  Kendo UI (2013.1.319) to javascripts pipeline
      insert  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
    deleting  Existing Kendo UI Style References
      adding  Kendo UI (2013.1.319) to styles pipeline
      insert  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
```

Lastly, If you are starting a new project right now I would advise you *against* using an apparently unmaintained gem. There are many other great frontend frameworks around such as [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), [Bourbon](http://bourbon.io/), [Zurb Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/) or [Semantic UI](http://semantic-ui.com/), just to name a few.

Comment: I also wanted to use Kendo UI with rails so contacted their support for the best way forward. The response was "Yikes - our Rails gem is way out of date.  I've got it on the list to get it updated." +1 for the Semantic UI comment. Wasn't aware of it and it looks very interesting.

Comment: Please excuse my stupidity. I was really inspired by your post but failed miserably but don't want to quit as I could be so close to success. I copied the .rb class file to my app folder on the local machine. After renaming the file and also the class as suggested I just get "Could not find generator kendoui_install".

Comment: @WaynePhipps have you double checked that the class and file are _exactly_ named `KendouiInstallGenerator` and `lib/kendoui/generators/kendoui_install_generator.rb`? Otherwise Rails' autoload mechanism won't find the task.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It's much appreciated. Unless I'm misunderstanding, the kendoui_install_generator.rb is in my app folder, the full path is /home/dev/rails_projects/kendo_ui/lib/kendoui/generators where kendo_ui is a test rails app

Comment: Oh now I see that there's a typo, the generator must be in `lib/generators/`, not in `lib/kendoui/generators/`. Sorry and thanks for pointing it out. I have edited my answer as well.

Comment: @WaynePhipps - Semantic UI & Kendo UI are like apple and oranges. Sematic ui is more compariable to zurb foundation or bootstrap. While KendoUI is  more like Wijmo, or Sencha or YUI3